# Invoke-Command into a remote host works in PowerShell terminal, not in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, powershell

This script works in a PowerShell terminal (32 bit host to a 64 bit target) :

```
PS C:\Users\Administrateur> $username=login
PS C:\Users\Administrateur> $pass=ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText password -Force
PS C:\Users\Administrateur> $cred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential
                                     -ArgumentList $username,$pass  
PS C:\Users\Administrateur> set-item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts
                                     TARGETHOST -Force
PS C:\Users\Administrateur> Invoke-Command -ComputerName TARGETHOST
                              -ScriptBlock { icacls "F:\WWW\file.txt" /grant GROUP:F }
                              -Authentication Negotiate -credential $cred
```

I need to set `Authentication` to `Negociate` to be able to log as a local remote user (`TARGETHOST\Administrator`).

I'm trying to reproduce it in VB.NET :

```
Imports System.Management.Automation
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Management.Automation.Runspaces

Public Class RemoteRightsManager

 ' Credential is already set up here '
 ' [...] '
 Public Function setRemoteRights(ByVal path As String,
                                     ByVal icaclsEntry As String) As Boolean
        Dim icaclsCommand As String = "icacls """ + path + """ /grant """ & icaclsEntry & """"
        setRemoteRights = True

        Dim psi As PowerShell
        Dim initial As InitialSessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault()
        Dim runspace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial)
        runspace.Open()

        psi = PowerShell.Create
        psi.Runspace = runspace
        psi.AddCommand("Set-Variable")
        psi.AddParameter("Name", "credential")
        psi.AddParameter("Value", Me.credential)
        psi.AddCommand("Set-Item")
        psi.AddArgument("wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts")
        psi.AddArgument(Me.host)
        psi.AddParameter("Force")
        psi.AddCommand("Invoke-Command")
        psi.AddParameter("ComputerName", Me.host)
        Dim block As ScriptBlock = ScriptBlock.Create(icaclsCommand )
        psi.AddParameter("ScriptBlock", block)
        psi.AddParameter("Authentication", "Negotiate")
        psi.AddParameter("Credential", credential)

        For Each item As PSObject In psi.Invoke()
            Console.WriteLine(item)
        Next
    End Function
End Class
```

I don't understand why, but `psi.Invoke()` seems to do absolutly nothing ; the execution never enters in the `For Each loop`, except if I comment most psi lines except the `ScriptBlock` one, and even, I don't catch the console output (seems to be another issue though).

Comment: You forgot `psi.AddStatement()` before `psi.AddCommand("Set-Item")` and before `psi.AddCommand("Invoke-Command")`. Also, what is inside `psi.Streams.Error` after calling `psi.Invoke()`?

Comment: I ran it on an upgraded environment (Windows 7 Professional, VS 2015) and it works ! Could you explain me why I need `AddStatement` ? I'll choose your answer as accepted.